# Changing Spinner Text Color from String.xml array

Tags: android, arrays, xml, android-spinner, textcolor

I want to change spinner text color (who is actually white) , to black .

I inserted string arrays in the spinner directly from string.xml file :

```
<resources>
....
...
<string name="vil_prompt">Choisir une ville</string>

<string-array name="vil_arrays">
    <item><FONT COLOR="#006600">Nouakchott Nord -Dar Naim </FONT></item>
    <item>Nouakchott Est - Tevrag Zeina</item>
    <item>Nouakchott Sud - Araffat</item>
    <item>Nouadhibou</item>
    <item>Rosso</item>
    <item>Adel baghrou</item>
    <item>Boughé</item>
    <item>Kiffa</item>
    <item>Zouerate</item>
    <item>kaédi</item>
    <item>Boû Gadoûm</item>
    <item>Boutilimit</item>
    <item>Atar</item>
    <item>Bareina</item>
    <item>Hamoud</item>
    <item>Mal</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

I find many different solution , but in majority of case , it was because they populated their spinner via the java code . i didn't initialized the spinner in the java file actually .

i found a solution who suggested to apply `<FONT COLOR>...</FONT>` to the string array but nothing changed (i applied the code to the first item as you can see)

[image: Pic]

i have two spinner , you can't actually see them because of the text color and background.

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:entries="@array/vil_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/vil_prompt"
        android:textColor="#808080"
        />
```

How to fix that ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *res/layou*t folder make a **custom_spinner_item.xml** file like:

```
<TextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle">
</TextView>
```

In your *java* file populate your `Spinner` like:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(YourActivity.this, R.array.vil_arrays, R.layout.custom_spinner_item);
```